# "If he saw that he should act" or "If he sees that he should act"

Tags: tenses

> If he **saw** that he should act immediately

or

> If he **sees** that he should act immediately

Any differences betweeen these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both valid.

There are five main different types of conditional sentence, and your examples fall into two of them.

The implicative form (sometimes called the zero conditional) covers the factual implications of one thing upon another:

> If he doesn't see anything, he can't act.
>
> If you don't eat, you will die.

It most often uses the present tense, but can use another tense when relevant only to the future or only to the past.

> Once, if you'd been caught stealing, you would have been hanged.

The predictive form (sometimes called the first conditional) covers possible future events, using the present tense for the conditional along with *will*, *shall*, or *should*:

> If there is a problem, I'll call you.
>
> If he sees that, he should act. (Your second example)

The hypothetical form (sometimes called the second conditional) covers hypothetical events.

> If I didn't have any coffee, I would take forever to get started.
>
> If he saw that[,] he should act immediately. (Your first example)

The past hypothetical form (sometimes called the third conditional) covers hypothetical events that did not come to pass.

> If the Cuba Missile Crisis had gone worse, there could have been a nuclear war.
>
> If he saw that[,] he should have acted immediately.

Note that in the first example the condition is something that didn't happen, in the second example it could either mean that the condition didn't happen (he didn't see "that") or that it did but the obliged action didn't happen (he did see "that", so he "should have acted", but he did not, or at least we suspect he might not have).

Finally the mixed conditional combines either a past condition with a present or future outcome, or a present condition with a past outcome.

> If I'd been able to stay in college, I'd have my degree by now.
>
> If I'd been trained in first-aid, I'd know what to do.

As you can see your examples fall into the predictive and hypothetical cases. There are often cases where you can choose relatively freely between the two (because what you think of hypothetically can still be plausible). As a rule, if you see the outcome as even remotely likely, then use the predictive:

> If he sees that, he should act.

If you are speaking hypothetically, then:

> If he saw that, he should act immediately.

Note that I add a comma to your examples. You need a comma when the condition comes first, not if it comes after:

> If he sees that, he should act.
>
> He should act if he sees that.
>
> If he saw that, he should act immediately.
>
> He should act immediately if he saw that.

Comment: This answer makes the (very reasonable) assumption that a comma was missing in the asker’s sentences, separating a protasis with a deictic object ‘that’ from the apodosis. If that is not the case, and the sentences are to be read as an incomplete conditional sentence, with only the protasis present, that contains an embedded relative clause [i.e., “If he sees/saw [that he should act immediately], then …”]; then the arguments for why both variants are correct would be different. The end result would still be the same, though: both are equally valid in the right context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet good point. The end-result is as you say the same, bar one thing, it is possible that such a clause would be part of the mixed case, rather than the predictive or hypothetical. Still, that remains covered in the above.

Answer (score 0):

**If he saw that he should act immediately** should be correct. There are 3 types of conditional sentences, and the first example you put falls under the second type.

Reference & further information: http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/conditional-sentences

Comment: And the second example falls under the first type.

Comment: Also, the "3 types" as often taught ignore both implications (sometimes added as the "zero type" before the 3 your link discusses) and the mixing. See my answer for a more complete version.